# GWT ExternalTextResource with large files

Tags: gwt, resources

I'm trying to get async a large html file with an ExternalTextResource:

```
public interface MyHtmlResources extends ClientBundle {

    public static final MyHtmlResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyHtmlResources.class);

    @Source("some.html")
    public ExternalTextResource getSomeHtml();
}

MyHtmlResources.INSTANCE.getSomeHtml().getText(new ResourceCallback<TextResource>() {
    public void onError(ResourceException e) { Window.alert(e.toString()); }
    public void onSuccess(TextResource r) {
        html.setHTML(r.getText());
    }
});
```

On Firefox the onError method always run with a message: `eval() returned null` and on Chrome I get `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Do you know if there is a way to work with large files? Am I limited to the maximum call stack size of each browser?

Thanks.

My "solution" was use RequestBuilder as mentioned on the Issue that italo post.

Comment: How large is large? Can you split these files into smaller pieces? Do you really need all that text in the browser?

Comment: "large" needs to be quantified and also WHY NO "IE" :D

Comment: I can't split, large is ~30MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that GWT parses the file content and it fails in some browsers when the file is big. Take a look at this issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6248